# Creating a mouse wheel navigation option for horizontal carousel of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I have made a horizontal carousel of images (and captions) using Twitter Bootstrap 4 and the **[perfect-scrollbar plugin](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar)**.

I want users to be able to navigate by using the *mouse wheel*. The plugin dos have a handlers option that I *did* use.

```js
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('#carousel', {
  maxScrollbarLength: 100,
  handlers: ['click-rail', 'drag-thumb', 'keyboard', 'wheel', 'touch']
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel li {
  padding: 0 0 70px 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#carousel li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#carousel li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#carousel li .caption {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
#carousel li h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#carousel li p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#carousel .ps__rail-x {
  background: #5C5C5C;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 40%;
}
#carousel .ps__thumb-x {
  height: 3px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  #carousel li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code-love.tk/demos/prop/lib/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" />
<script src="https://code-love.tk/demos/prop/lib/js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <ul id="carousel">
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/people" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p>O poveste adevarata</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/arch" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animals" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Into the wild</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work the expected way. Like **[THIS](https://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/mMLQQb)**, for instance.

**Questions:**

1. Am I using it wrong, or does the plugin not have such an option?
2. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: I don't believe this plugin does what you think it does, at least not in this manner. What you've done is set the scrollbar's width and added handlers that just make scrolling smoother for those handling methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option built in the plugin for this" `useBothWheelAxes: true`.

```js
var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('#carousel', {
  maxScrollbarLength: 100,
  useBothWheelAxes: true
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel li {
  padding: 0 0 70px 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#carousel li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#carousel li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#carousel li .caption {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
#carousel li h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#carousel li p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#carousel .ps__rail-x {
  background: #5C5C5C;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 40%;
}
#carousel .ps__thumb-x {
  height: 3px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  #carousel li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code-love.tk/demos/prop/lib/css/perfect-scrollbar.css" />
<script src="https://code-love.tk/demos/prop/lib/js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <ul id="carousel">
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/people" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p>O poveste adevarata</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/arch" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animals" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Into the wild</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```